# What are the recommended size multipliers when trying to create images for iPad (previously iPhone only app)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am trying to make my app universal so now I have universal image sets but apparently I need to make separate iPad sets. I have images in my Assets that fit an iPhone the way I want, and I can scale up for 2x and 3x, etc. but when I go to iPad what would be the size comparison for the first (standard) iPad image? I just don't know, relatively which of my iPhone images I should use and how much to increase it by for my starting point on iPads.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what issue you're having and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I built an app for iPhone, but now am trying to make it universal. This is the first time I have tried to go from iPhone to Universal so I have found it strange that I select Universal on my Image Assets window but I have to also select iPad and make additional sizes. For example, Universal-1 is 64x64 and Universal-1@2x is 128x128, but what would iPad-1 be relative tot he other images?